# Is there a way for Visual C++ code to detect when the profiler is running?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Performance Analysis in Visual Studio 2012 with a C++ project. I was wondering if there are any API calls available for a program to detect when it's running under the profiler? E.g.:

```
int runCount = 1;
if (IsProfiling()) {
    runCount = 100;
}
for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++) {
     DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: While an interesting theoretical question, practically speaking profiling different code than actually runs normally is probably not helpful, the same way profiling debug builds doesn't usually provide useful information.

Comment: The issue is mostly sample size - if DoSomething only runs for say 800ms, I don't get many samples. Running it 100 times gives a better breakdown of its bottlenecks.

Comment: Ah, looks like I can also change sample rate in the profiling settings - didn't see the properties box in that sidebar context menu.